# How to get output from netsh using python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, dhcp, netsh

Can anyone please advise what am I doing wrong, that there is no output showed when executing netsh command on windows using python subprocess library?

Example:

```
p = subprocess.run('netsh dhcp show server', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output: empty string

When I execute some other command, etc. echo Hi, I get an output:

```
p = subprocess.run('echo Hi', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

My intention is to get list of our DHCP servers and parse the output.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Windows at all, and don't have a Windows box nearby, but could it be that 1. `netsh` doesn't actually give any output in this case, have you checked it in `cmd`? and 2. `netsh` actually prints information to stderr, so you have to capture it also? So you can try to call run() with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and see if it works.

Comment: You are right, the command works if I execute it in cmd, but when I try it out Pycharm Terminal or I run the script in cmd nothing is returned.

Comment: So, have you tried redirecting stderr to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code page of the process to UTF-8 before executing sub-processes.

```
chcp 65001
```